# How to define a new column in a data frame based on row-wise condition of different sets of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I’d like to have a new column, `score`, with below conditions. I am not sure how to code this with R. tried with `rowSums` which is not helpful. Would appreciate any help on this (maybe with dplyr!)
Preferably the `score` should have values as `2, NA, 1, 0, 1, NA`

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(NA, 1, 1, 0, 1 , NA),
                x2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA),
                x3 = c(1, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA),
                x4 = c(1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1))

x$score <- (rowSums(x[c("x1", "x2")] == 1, na.rm = F) > 0) +
  (rowSums(x[c("x3", "x4")] == 1, na.rm = F) > 0)
```

### Condition for X1 and X2

- If x1 **or** x2 equal to one -> 1 score
- Neither x1 **or** x2 equal to one -> 0 score
- If both x1 **and** x2 equal to NA -> NA

### Condition for x3 and x4

- If x3 **or** x4 equal to one -> 1 score
- Neither x3 **or** x4 equal to one -> 0 score
- If both x3 **and** x4 equal to NA -> NA

Comment: I don't understand your desired result. You are calculating a score for x1&x2 and x3&x4, then are you combining them? You don't seem to be adding them because the first row would have 2 I think.

Comment: Specifically, in row 1: `x2` is a 1, so `1`, then `x3`/`x4` are both 1, so another `1` ... `1 + 1 = 1`?

Comment: What if you had 0,0,1,1 should the result be 0 or 1?

Comment: Sorry about my mistake. I revised my question. I should've put 2 not 1 for first element of desired `score` column since both `x1`/`x2` and `x3`/`x4` satisfied one score and summing them up result in 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding two `case_when` statements, no need to go row-wise. In order to match your intended output, we need to `pmin` the score back down to 1, clearly the case for the first row where both pairs (`x2 == 1` and `x3 == 1`) would sum to 2.

```r
x %>%
  mutate(
    score =
      case_when(is.na(x1) & is.na(x2) ~ NA, x1 == 1 | x2 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0L) + 
      case_when(is.na(x3) & is.na(x4) ~ NA, x3 == 1 | x4 == 1 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ 0L)
  )
#   x1 x2 x3 x4 score
# 1 NA  1  1  1     2
# 2  1  1 NA NA    NA
# 3  1  0  0  0     1
# 4  0  0 NA  0     0
# 5  1 NA  0  0     1
# 6 NA NA NA  1    NA
```

Comment: Sorry hahaa. That was supposed to be in the main comment. Not under solution. Yes yes, this was meant for OP. Must have clicked the wrong comment section.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I've revised my question so `score = pmin(1, score)` is not needed anymore.